# Accessing Spark Mllib Bisecting K-means tree data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Looking over the source code for Bisecting K-means it seems that it builds an internal tree representation of the cluster assignments at each level it progresses. Is it possible to get access to that tree? The built-in methods only give the cluster assignment at the leafs and not the nodes.

Comment: Wondering exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Follow up on this: has anyone modified the Spark ML source code to be able to store & return the hierarchical clustering tree structure?

I found a GitHub repo with intro to MLlib 1.6's implementation of Bisecting K-means Clustering: https://github.com/yu-iskw/bisecting-kmeans-blog/blob/master/blog-article.md

In the section "What's Next?", the first JIRA ticket [SPARK-11664] "Add methods to get bisecting k-means cluster structure" (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11664) seems to be the request to obtain the hierarchical cluster tree structure as a built-in effort. As of today, this ticket status is marked as "resolved".

However, in Spark MLlib's latest implementation (2.4.4) as follows, we didn't find this tree structure, or dendrogram to be a built-in output:

PySpark MLlib 2.4.4 official documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.BisectingKMeans
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.BisectingKMeansModel

Scala MLlib 2.4.4 official documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.BisectingKMeans
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.BisectingKMeansModel

We also looked up into their source code, and it does not seem to have the hierarchical tree structure stored as built-in output?

If the hierarchical clustering tree structure is not available in Spark MLlib 2.4.4 BisectingKMeans, does anyone know if there's modified the source code to get the tree structure available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to get this via the pyspark API, but **if you save a `BisectingKMeansModel` to disk, it writes Parquet files that allow you to reconstruct the tree.**

From Python I was not able to get this to work using the deprecated `pyspark.mllib` package, but instead use `pyspark.ml`.  Specifically, [`pyspark.ml.clustering.BisectingKMeansModel`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.clustering.BisectingKMeansModel.html) exposes a `.save(path)` method.

```py
from pyspark.ml.clustering import BisectingKMeans

k=30
bkm = BisectingKMeans(k=k, minDivisibleClusterSize=1.0)
bkm.setMaxIter(10)
model = bkm.fit(examples)
model.save("path/to/saved_model")
```

Now separately, in Python, I use Pyarrow to load the serialized model from the "data" subdirectory:

```py
from pyarrow import parquet as pq

tabl = pq.read_table("path/to/saved_model/data/")
nodesdf = tabl.to_pandas()
print(nodesdf)
```

```
    index  size    center      norm          cost    height    children
0       0   147  {'typ...  4.573446    242.518210  0.000000          []
1       1    88  {'typ...  4.635275    151.815024  0.000000          []
2      -5   228  {'typ...  4.576475    378.479211  0.740183      [0, 1]
3       2    22  {'typ...  4.568550    312.282380  0.000000          []
4      -4   250  {'typ...  4.511299    837.245032  2.464225     [-5, 2]
```

Each row of the table represents a node in the dendrogram.

Leaf nodes have empty `children`. Root and inner nodes use the `children` list to reference the `index` column of their children rows. (It seems that another way to distinguish the two types of node is whether the `index` is negative or not.)

The leaf nodes (rows returned by `nodesdf.loc[nodesdf["children"].str.len() == 0]` correspond to what the model exposes through it's pyspark API:

- The set of leaf nodes returned by the following query is equal to what's returned by `model.clusterCenters()`
- The `index` column of a leaf node corresponds to the cluster id that the model ultimately predicts for a datapoint in the pyspark API (`model.transform(examples)`).  So you could write some code to tie together datapoints to their place in the dendrogram.